# How to share a database connection with a joblet in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a job with a tMSSqlConnection setup, and I need to share that connection with a joblet.  I found instructions online saying to register it as a shared connection, and then add an option in dynamic settings of the joblet components with that connection name, so it can be selected from the component list of connections.  However Java is complaining when I try to do this.

The job + joblet works fine if I do not try to share the connection.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that you need to put a pre-job in the joblet and then connect the tMSSQLconnection, and then use the share or register a connection, as UmeshR mentioned.  But the thing I was missing was that you CAN put a pre-job in a joblet.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add tMSSQLconnection component in JobLet
2. Click on register connection check box.
3. Give the same "Shared DB connection name" which has been assigned in parent job.
4. use joblet`s connection component name in drop down list.

this will solve your problem.

Comment: But how do you connect the tMSSQLconnection to the joblet flow?